# Why isnt my dax custom sorting function working

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a Matrix visualization in Power BI. I would like to custom sort a field called [Risk]. There are three types of [risk]: low, moderate & high.
I created a new column Sort Risk: Low = 1, moderate =2 and high =3 using dax. I told Power BI to sort by [Sort Risk].

```
Sort Risk = SWITCH([Risk], "low",1,"moderate",2,"high",3)
```

[image]

Power BI is not doing it. What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I told Power BI to sort by [Sort Risk].

I don't think so.  That should have failed because of a circular dependency. eg

[image]

Instead add [Sort Risk] in Power Query,

```
Table.AddColumn(#"NameOfPreviousStep", "Sort Risk", each if [Risk] = "Low" then 1 else if [Risk] = "Moderate" then 2 else if [Risk] = "High" then 3 else null, type number)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. 
I can’t figure out how to implement your solution. 
I didn’t get any errors for the dax i wrote.

Comment: see updated answer.  Configuring Risk to have "Sort Risk" as the "Sort by column" should fail.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work for me. I tried it exacttly how you wrote it. I got an error message when I did it.